# Calculating the B flux density of a flat spiral coil with N turns

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider the [following topology for a flat spiral coil](http://coil32.net/images/img/calc/FlatSpiralCoilDim.jpg) (with an air gap in the middle). It's been a very long time since I have used Maxwell's Equations and now I find myself trying to figure out the $\vec{B}$ flux density of the following arrangement, assuming a current is flowing through the coiled wire. The primary assumption here is that the current in the wire cannot jump due to thing insulation between each winding.

My initial guess was to construct an Ampèrian Loop across just either the lhs or rhs wire group and then compute a line integral of the enclosed current. My other idea was to construct an Ampèrian Loop that spans just the central wire and the air gap, however I'm generally at a loss due to being pretty damn rusty.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, Vhaanzeit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to know the $B$ field in the center: [for a single loop](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c2) with radius $R$, the field is $B=\mu_0I/(2R)$. Then sum over all the loops.

Comment: I think that should cover it. Thanks very much for the swift reply!